# How can I extract data points contained in matplotlib Path vertices?

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, vertices

I define the vertices of a polygon and their types as follows:

```
verts=[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(0,0)]
codes=[Path.MOVETO,Path.LINETO,Path.LINETO,Path.LINETO,Path.CLOSEPOLY]
path=Path(verts,codes)
patch=patches.PathPatch(path)
```

Now I would like to extract the indices of the data points contained inside the vertices so that I can manipulate them.  I tried the following:

```
datapts = np.column_stack((x_data,y_data))
inds, = Path(verts).contains_points(datapts)
```

but of course the verts themselves are not data and so this doesn't work.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

3 minutes after I posted the above I found the answer:

```
inds = path.contains_points(datapts)
```

This can be used as follows:

```
ax.plot(x_data[inds], y_data[inds])
```